# How do I remove "Provider=..." from a connection string

Tags: c#, regex

I have an SSIS with a sql task and a c# script task.

It has a project parameter `conn` (of type string) with this value:

```
Data Source=serverName;Initial Catalog=dbName;Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;
```

The sql task uses oledb connection and the oledb connection uses this string. The sql task calls a stored procedure. This sql task works.

The c# script task also needs to use this and it uses `SqlConnection`.
(I could use a separate project parameter that doesn't contain "Provider" but that doesn't seem efficient)

However, `SqlConnection` doesn't like keyword "Provider" and I can't change this to use `OleDbConnection` (I'm not strong in c#).

Therefore I need to somehow remove `Provider=blabla` from this string. I'm thinking of String.replace with regex.

How do I do this?

Thank you!

Comment: It works! Thank you that was succinct.
Edit:
I actually tried this and it works too but yours is much better imo
"var newConn = new OleDbConnectionStringBuilder(conn);
newConn.Remove("Provider");
conn = newConn.ToString();"

Comment: As a rule of thumb, never create or manipulate connection strings directly, use the corresponding **ConnectionStringBuilder** to handle it.

Answer (score 4):

In general it's safer to not modify a connection string directly, but instead to use the specific provider's `ConnectionStringBuilder` to do it for you:

```
var conn = " Data Source=serverName;Initial Catalog=dbName;Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Integrated Security=SSPI; ";
var connBldr = new OleDbConnectionStringBuilder(conn);
connBldr.Remove("provider");
conn = connBldr.ConnectionString;
```

---

That being said, another way to do it is to split the string on the `;` character, remove any parts that contain "provider", and then join them back again with the `;` character:

```
conn = string.Join(";", conn.Split(';').Where(c => 
    !c.TrimStart().StartsWith("provider", true, null)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have two different clients with different needs, I would use two strings. Are you storing both sets of code in the same directory?

If you want to stick with one string, I suppose the easiest approach is

`connectionString.Replace("Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;", "");`

You could also move that element to the end of the string, get the index of "Provider=" and only read from 0-index. That would protect your code from someone changing to a different provider in the future.

`connectionString.SubString(0, s.IndexOf("Provider="));`