# How to execute SqlCommand using OLEDB connection in SSIS script component

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, oledbconnection, script-task

I am using SSIS 2019 and am able to execute SQL Command with ADO.Net Connection Manager.
I want to use OLEDB connection manager in a Script component within a Data Flow Task and I am getting the below error:

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to class type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection'. Instances of types that represent COM components cannot be cast to types that do not represent COM components; however they can be cast to interfaces as long as the underlying COM component supports QueryInterface calls for the IID of the interface.

[image]
Can someone please let me know if we can use OLEDB Connection in SSIS script component in a Data flow.

Here is code for connection strings

```
  public override void PreExecute()
    {
        string conn = this.Connections.Connection.ConnectionString;
    }
```

I am not getting build error in script C# code. But getting error at script component.

Comment: Why not just use .Net SqlConnection since you’re writing a .Net script task?

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I want to use Package.config as it deploys in multiple environments.

Comment: Ok.  That will work either way.

Comment: You need to provide the C# code you are using within the script

Comment: Updated description with c# code.but issue at script component.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Using a Script Component

To access a connection manager within a script component, you should first specify this connection manager from the script component editor as shown in the image below:

[image]

Then, within the script component, you should use the `Connections` variable to access this connection manager *(In this example, the connection manager assigned name is `Connection`)*:

```cs
var constr  = Connections.Connection.ConnectionString;
```

*screenshot*

[image]

### Executing a SQL command using C#

Next, you should use this connection string to initiate a `SqlConnection` object in order to use it by a `SqlCommand` as follows:

```cs
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(constr))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Write here your SQL command", conn))
    {
        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Make sure you added a reference for `using System.Data.SqlClient` to use the `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` objects.

**Important Note:** If you are using SQL authentication, you should re-add the password to the connection string since it will not be retrieved from the connection manager for security reasons.

### Using a Script Task

You should first retrieve the OLE DB connection string from the connection manager using the following command:

```cs
string constr = Dts.Connections["OledbCM"].ConnectionString;
```

#### Demonstration

I added `Messagebox.Show(constr)` command to the script task to show how the connection string looks like once retrieved:

[image]

---

#### Helpful Links:

- [SSIS Script Task : ConnectionString for ADO.Net & OleDb ConnectionManager](http://akshaya-m.blogspot.com/2017/02/ssis-script-task-connectionstring-for.html)
- [Check OLDEDB database Connection using script task in SSIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/199662/check-oldedb-database-connection-using-script-task.html)

---

### Update 1: SqlConnection vs. OleDbConnection

Since you are using `SqlConnection` class which represents a connection to a SQL Server database. You will encounter the following error while trying to use the connection string retrieved from an OleDb Connection:

> Keyword not supported "Provider"

The main reason is that the OleDB connection requires that the connection string contains the provider information since it has the ability to connect to different providers such as Oracle, Excel, Access, SQL. While `SqlConnection` class does not support this information since it is only using the SQL Server Native client provider.

#### How to solve this issue?

You can simply use a `System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionStringBuilder` object to remove this part using the following code:

```cs
string con = Dts.Connections["OledbCM"].ConnectionString;
var connBldr = new OleDbConnectionStringBuilder(con);
connBldr.Remove("Provider");
con  = connBldr.ConnectionString;
```

Or you can use Linq: *(Remember to add the `System.Linq` namespace)*

```cs
string con = Dts.Connections["OledbCM"].ConnectionString;
con = string.Join(";", con.Split(';').Where(c =>
    !c.TrimStart().StartsWith("Provider")));
```

#### References

- [How do I remove "Provider=..." from a connection string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63525761/how-do-i-remove-provider-from-a-connection-string)

Comment: I tried to access DTS.Connections which is giving me error stating "The type or namespace name 'Connections' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime'" even after adding Microsoft.SqlServer.Managed.DTS.dll. Please let me know if the script task is on Dataflow or Control flow. I am facing issue and need it on Dataflow with script task and able to access OLEDB connection

Comment: Are you using a [script task or a script component](https://www.sqlshack.com/ssis-script-task-vs-script-component/)?

Comment: I am using script component. I want to use OLEDB connection in Script component.

Comment: @AMDI check my answer update

Comment: @Hadi- I tried this earlier and I am getting error as "Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to class type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection'" on script Component it self when I changed the connection to OLEDB connection. Please let me know if there are any settings to be changed

Comment: @AMDI you need to get the connection string into a string variable then use it to create a new SQLConnection object as is mentioned in my answer.

Comment: Note that there are some differences between OleDB and SqlClient connection strings, although many of the basic options are identical.  It may not always be possible to simply reuse an OleDb connection string, and you'd need to configure and pass separate variables for the relevant connection string components. Or parse and manipulate it with OleDbConnectionStringBuilder https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbconnectionstringbuilder?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0

Comment: @Hadi - I tried your suggestion but how to get rid of error at script component

Comment: @AMDI can you provide the full error stack trace and your c# script, since I need to know if it is thrown on the PreExecute() method, or on another line of code.

Comment: @Hadi- Getting exception "ssis error keyword not supported 'provider'"

Comment: @AMDI you are on the right track. You should remove the provider part from the connection string since `SQLConnection` does not support the `Provider` keyword in the connection string while `OLEDBConnection` does. Check my answer update to learn how to remove the `Provider` part.

Comment: @AMDI I updated my answer. Please let me know that it still not working